# IE SEC7111 HTTPS security is compromised by http:// with Angular 6

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, x-frame-options

I know this is a question already discussed but following various solutions my problem is still present! I've a web app developed in Angular 6, let's call it 'ExternalApp', containing an IFrame in which show pages contained in another app, let's call it 'InternalApp'. Opening an InternalApp page on Chrome and Firefox I've no problem, it's correctly showed, but on IE 11 I've this error in console:

```
SEC7111: HTTPS security is compromised by https://internalAppPage
```

I tried to set response header on InternalApp in this way:

```
response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "allow-from https://internalAppPage");
response.addHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors https://internalAppPage");
```

I understood X-Frame-Options is overrided by Content-Security-Policy on Chrome and Firefox. Instead, on IE Content-Security-Policy isn't compatible, so X-Frame-Options is valid. 
My question is: is it right to set header in InternalApp? Or is ExternalApp responsible to allow url to shwn in IFrame?

Many thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Try to go to Internet options->Security tab->Custom Level and Enable the 'Display mixed content' option. You can refer this link may give more information about handling mixed content. Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/22/handling-mixed-httpshttps-content/

Comment: Already done.... no changes

Comment: You can try to check in the network tab of the developer tools whether any file is using HTTP protocol. If you find any then you can try to use HTTPS for that file may help to solve this issue.

Comment: Yes, there is an HTTP call in network, but I don't do it in my code. I think IE does it but I don't know why and where I can modify it.

Comment: Browser will not do anything by itself. IE will also not do that. Did you check which kind of file is it? If possible, you can try to share the snapshot of Network tab. It can help to know about that HTTP call.

Comment: I see various call to index of InternalApp, one of which is http and the others are https. All this are call to the same file, index.html. For this reason I thought IE does this mutiple call.

Comment: Can you see the similar results by using any other browser? or other browsers just make a single call?

Comment: Other browsers make multiple call to index.html but no one with http... all calls are https

Comment: We need to check the site to understand the issue properly. Only description will not give much idea. You can also try to test the issue with lowest security settings for IE browser to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not related to X-Frame-Options or Content-Security-Policy. IE11 throws that error on mixed content (mixing HTTP and HTTPS connections). Most likely the outer frame is HTTP and the inner frame is HTTPS. This is only warned against in IE, the others only block and show error when the outer frame is HTTPS and the inner is HTTP.

But, according to other answers it can also be caused by

```
document.write('something');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The outer frame is HTTPS but I don't do HTTP call in inner frame. I think IE does this call. I also don't do any document.write('something')...